# Java Code to Open a password protected zip file which is opening only with 7zx and keka in mac OS

Tags: java, compression, codec, 7zip, recordreader

I have a password protected zip file which is opening only with 7zx and keka in mac.
I have to write the code in java to decompress password protected zip file and then do some operation on it.
I have tried using sevenz api in apache.commons.compress but I am not able to compress it getting exception,
bad 7z signature.Is there any api support for decompressing the zip files?

```
unzip -P test@123 abcd.zip
Archive:  abcd.zip
   skipping: abcd.txt  need PK compat. v5.1 (can do v2.1)
```

Comment: you are not able to compress it getting exception? what is it? You are asking about decompression and getting error on compressing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i remember there is a library namely **zip4j**, check out this [link](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/)

And try this code:

```
//zip password
String pass="abc";
try {
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("dir/xyz.zip");
      if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
         zipFile.setPassword(pass);
    }
//extract somewhere in directory
zipFile.extractAll("dir/abc");
} 
 catch (ZipException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: My pleasure :) @yanky

Comment: Hey @Tahir Hussain Mir-The problem is I have all the files in hdfs and not in local file system,so is there any way to do that in hdfs and not in local

Comment: I answered Your above question based on previous requirement. You have to write a new question in stackOverFlow mentioning the new issue "HDFS"..
May be someone related to hdfs may help.
Thanks :) @yanky